# Parent WPF ListBox doesnt Scroll when the mouse cursor is over a item of its ListBox inside?

Tags: wpf

I have a ListBox(Parent) and a ListBox inside it(Child). I can't scroll through the items of parent ListBox if the mouse cursor is over a item of child ListBox. How to we can scroll through the parent control irrespective of the item under the mouse cursor. Thanks for help me!

**i found a solution for this issues:**

```
private void listBox1_PreviewMouseWheel(object sender, MouseWheelEventArgs e)
    {
        var scrollViwer = GetScrollViewer(sender as DependencyObject) as ScrollViewer;
        if (scrollViwer != null)
        {
            if (e.Delta < 0)
            {
                scrollViwer.ScrollToVerticalOffset(scrollViwer.VerticalOffset + 3);
            }
            else if (e.Delta > 0)
            {
                scrollViwer.ScrollToVerticalOffset(scrollViwer.VerticalOffset - 3);
            }
        }
    }

    public static DependencyObject GetScrollViewer(DependencyObject o)
    {
        if (o is ScrollViewer)
        { return o; }

        for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(o); i++)
        {
            var child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(o, i);

            var result = GetScrollViewer(child);
            if (result == null)
            {
                continue;
            }
            else
            {
                return result;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: When you want to scroll child?

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply @sac1, currently i only want scroll through the items of parent ListBox.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way to solve this:

- Set `IsEnabled=false` on Child Listbox

but I don't now what is your final goal. Btw ScrollViewer (Attached property of ListBox) has tons of property to setup your prefered behavior.